# Search algorithm of my website search

Tags: algorithm, search

I have business web dire ctory and have a problem with the search algorithm.Lets say i have category: "Accountants".But when a user make a search and type lets say: "Accounting Companies" or "Accountancy" ,the results from the category "Accountants" will not come up.How can i solve this problem?I mean is there a way to include all synonyms and different versions of category names in the search algorithm?
P.S: My site is built with CakePHP framework

Comment: The google term for this is "stemming". It is not perfect, but it might give you some new thoughts. (the other way is "equivalence classes", which is much harder)

Answer (score 0):

I would use elastic search + soundex. if you search is really simple and you dont need use elasticsearch or other tool, look how to use soundex in your database enginner.